# Day 9 Secret Auction Program from 100 Days of Code with Dr. Angela Yu

Tags: python, dictionary, replit

Can someone help me with this? What am I doing wrong? I checked Dr. Angela Yu's solution. She solves the problem in a different way but I am not able to understand where I am making mistakes.

This program should print the name and the bid of the highest bidder. However, when I run this code, the console prints the bid and the name that was entered at the end.

```py
from replit import clear
#HINT: You can call clear() to clear the output in the console.

from art import logo
print (logo)

game_end = False

bids = {}

while not game_end:

  name = input("What is your name?\n")
  bid = int(input("How much are you bidding? $"))
  
  bids[name] = bid
  game = input("Are there any other bidders. y or n\n").lower()
  
  if game == "n":
    game_end = True
    
  else:
    clear()
    
highest_bid = 0

for bidder in bids:
  if bid > highest_bid:
    highest_bid = bid
    winner = bidder
print(f"The winner is {winner} with a bid of ${highest_bid}")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not considering the value of `bid` that was stored in the dict `bids`. You just need to get that value as you are iterating:

```py
for bidder, bid in bids.items():
  if bid > highest_bid:
    highest_bid = bid
    winner = bidder
print(f"The winner is {winner} with a bid of ${highest_bid}")
```

By using `bids.items()`, the dict yields both the name (`bidder`) and the value of the bid (`bid`)

Alternatively you can sort `bids` and extract the last (highest) bid:

```py
winner,highest_bid = sorted(bids.items(), key=lambda item:item[1])[-1]
print(f"The winner is {winner} with a bid of ${highest_bid}")
```

You could change your code to be more like Dr. Angela's like this:

```py
for bidder in bids:
  bid = bids[bidder]     # This is what Dr. Angela does
  if bid > highest_bid:
    highest_bid = bid
    winner = bidder
print(f"The winner is {winner} with a bid of ${highest_bid}")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would like to tell you that I am pretty much a beginner at this. Apparently, you used the item function. I don't know how that works. Also you used two entries in a for loop. I am not sure what that means either. Dr. Angela has mentioned her solution to this problem. Could you please tell me what she does differently that makes the program work for her and not me? Her code is mentioned in the link https://replit.com/@appbrewery/blind-auction-completed#main.py.

Comment: It seems Dr. Angela uses: `bid_amount = bidding_record[bidder]`. Your code could do: `bid = bids[bidder]`

Comment: So I should assign the values in the dictionary to "bid" even though I have already entered the values for "bid" when I declared it to be a variable?

Comment: I will update my answer to show the options you have.

Comment: Thank you very much for updating your comment.